# Bootstrap modal close on enter key press

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to write a code which enables one to close the open bootstrap modals once you hit the enter key.

this is my code:

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if(e.keyCode==13){
         if(!$(e.target).closest('.modal fade in').length) {
             $('.modal').each(function(){
                $(this.previousSibling).modal('hide');
            });
         }
     }
});
```

please help, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You probably don't need the `fade in`, and since there's should be only one modal window open at a time, you probably don't need the `.each` either...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, how can i target the open modal then without ``each``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did simply:

```
$('.modal').modal('hide');
```

and all open modals closed.

what  the heck! :D